# two polymer elements (paper-input) referencing the same object on different instance variable does not work

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I have two polymer elements (paper-input) referencing the same object on different instance variable.

When I change the text on one paper-input element, another paper-element does not change, although the referenced object has changed.

Following details:

**>>> Browser**

[image]

**>>> main_app.html**

```
<dom-module id="main-app">
  <template>
    <h3>Lista de Produtos</h3>
    <paper-fab icon="add" on-tap="adicionarProduto"></paper-fab>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{produtos}}" as="item">
      <div class="layout vertical">
        <paper-material elevation="1">
        <div class="layout horizontal">
          <paper-input label="Produto" value="{{item.descricao}}"></paper-input>
        </div>
        </paper-material>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{item.componentes}}" as="item_comp">
          <div class="layout vertical">
            <div class="layout horizontal">
              <paper-input label="Produto Componente" value="{{item_comp.descricao}}"></paper-input>
            </div>
          </div>
        </template>
      </div>
    </template>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

**>>> main_app.dart**

```
@PolymerRegister('main-app')
class MainApp extends PolymerElement {
  @property
  List<Produto> produtos = new List();

  MainApp.created() : super.created();

  void ready() {
    Produto p = new Produto()..descricao = 'teste';
    add('produtos', p);

    Produto p2 = new Produto()..descricao = 'teste 2';
    add('produtos', p2);

    Produto p3 = new Produto()..descricao = 'teste3';
    add('produtos', p3);
    add('produtos.2.componentes', p);
    add('produtos.2.componentes', p2);
  }

  @reflectable
  void adicionarProduto(e, d) {
    //...
  }
}

class Produto extends JsProxy {
  @property
  String descricao;
  @property
  List<Produto> componentes;
  Produto() {
    componentes = new List();
  }
}
```

Is this a bug or something else needs to be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug, because Polymer won't observe internal property changes, so when you edit the description, the value is updated but the other input does not get notified and it doesn't update its value.

One way to solve your problem would be to add an on-change handler to the input elements. In the listener code call `this.notifyPath(itemPath)`.

You need to generate the correct path e.g 'produtos.3.descricao' so you need the index of the element. For that you can use the `indexForElement` method of the `dom-repeat`

```
//inside the change event listener (js code)
//You need to give your dom-repeat and id
var index = this.$.myDomRepeatTemplateId.indexForElement(ev.target)
```

Comment: Ok , I understand it is for now. We hope that in the near future , polymer can handle this transparently. Would be great!

Comment: You actually shouldn't need to call notifyPath in this case, only if you are setting values in your dart code. You are using all the proper apis where you do this so it seems that something else is going on.

Comment: @JakeMacDonald, I'm not familiar with Dart , Is there an additional 'observer' functionality that the JS version does not have? Otherwise I don't see how it would work without notifyPath because Polymer by design does not monitor internal properties.

Comment: Nevermind, after I looked more closely I see why this is necessary.

You should be able to use the `linkPaths` method though, but I haven't experimented with it yet.

Comment: ok, so this is ugly but adding the following works:

    linkPaths('produtos.2.componentes.0', 'produtos.#0');
    linkPaths('produtos.2.componentes.1', 'produtos.#1');
    linkPaths('produtos.0', 'produtos.#2.componentes.#0');
    linkPaths('produtos.1', 'produtos.#2.componentes.#1');

Comment: Interesting! I will study more this alternative... Maybe a day we may have a stronger databinding, where changes to the model are reflected in its elements and vice versa, through their logical relationships.

Answer (score 1):

`@property`/`@Property()` is only for Polymer elements. Use `@reflectable` for model class members.

```
class Produto extends JsProxy {
  @reflectable
  String descricao;
  @reflectable
  List<Produto> componentes;
  Produto() {
    componentes = new List();
  }
}
```

Building on @HugoZapata s answer I created a working example https://github.com/bwu-dart-playground/polymer1/tree/master/nested_repeat_complex_data
The recursivity in your model makes this quite a challenge. Maybe there is a simpler way, but this is what I was able to make work.

Comment: Günter, you already helped me with this information (`@reflectable`for model class members) on another post. For curiosity I put the `@property` annotation and worked too. Which is the real differences between `@property` and `@reflectable`?

Comment: For model classes you only need `@reflectable` in order for JS to be able to access the members. `@Property()` is a more complex annotation with additional "features" which only work on real Polymer elements, but it includes what `@reflectable` provides. Therefore on a model class use `@reflectable`