# Polymer linkPaths does not fire on-change et all

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer, polymer-1.0

**EDITED: NOW WITH COMPLETE CODE**

[Previous Post related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33427409/two-polymer-elements-paper-input-referencing-the-same-object-on-different-inst)

LinkPaths works, but does not fire all on-change event of the elements where the data changed. See the image:

[image]

For example, when data is changed on `<paper-input label="Produto" value="{{item.descricao}}"></paper-input>` (outer dom-repeat) the data in element `<paper-input label="Produto Componente" value="{{item_comp.descricao}}" on-change="mudou"></paper-input>` (inner dom-repeat) change too. It´s works nice because of the linkPaths!

But `on-change="mudou"` does not fire.

Just fire if data entry directly on `<paper-input label="Produto Componente" value="{{item_comp.descricao}}" on-change="mudou"></paper-input>` (inner dom-repeat)

**main_app.html**

```
<dom-module id="main-app">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>

  <template>
    <h3>Lista de Produtos</h3>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{produtos}}" as="item">
      <div class="layout vertical">
        <paper-material elevation="1">
        <div class="layout horizontal">
          <paper-input label="Produto" value="{{item.descricao}}"></paper-input>
        </div>
        </paper-material>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{item.componentes}}" as="item_comp">
          <div class="layout vertical">
            <div class="layout horizontal">
              <paper-input label="Produto Componente" value="{{item_comp.descricao}}" on-change="mudou"></paper-input>
            </div>
          </div>
        </template>
      </div>
    </template>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

**main_app.dart**

```
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:polymer_elements/paper_input.dart';
import 'package:polymer_elements/paper_fab.dart';
import 'package:polymer_elements/iron_icons.dart';
import 'package:polymer_elements/paper_material.dart';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:web_components/web_components.dart';

@PolymerRegister('main-app')
class MainApp extends PolymerElement {
  @Property(notify: true)
  List<Produto> produtos = new List();

  MainApp.created() : super.created();

  void ready() {
    Produto p = new Produto()..descricao = 'componente 1';
    add('produtos', p);

    Produto p2 = new Produto()..descricao = 'componente 2';
    add('produtos', p2);

    Produto p3 = new Produto()..descricao = 'composto';
    add('produtos', p3);
    add('produtos.2.componentes', p);
    add('produtos.2.componentes', p2);

    linkPaths('produtos.2.componentes.0', 'produtos.#0');
    linkPaths('produtos.2.componentes.1', 'produtos.#1');
    linkPaths('produtos.0', 'produtos.#2.componentes.#0');
    linkPaths('produtos.1', 'produtos.#2.componentes.#1');
  }

  @reflectable
  void adicionarProduto(e, d) {
    //...
  }

  @reflectable
  mudou(e, d) {
    window.alert('teste');
  }
}

class Produto extends JsProxy {
  @reflectable
  String descricao;
  @reflectable
  List<Produto> componentes;
  Produto() {
    componentes = new List();
  }
}
```

Is this normal in Polymer? How I can to force fire on-change?

Comment: An event is fired when `notify: true` is set on the property. Didn't have a closer look at the code just now though.

Comment: In previous post (link above), the code is complete. I have a list (`@property produtos`)  of the JsProxy that contains an list of the JsProxy that reference objects of the first list (`@property`). This form, I can use `notify: true` just fist list, not excatly on field that change, because it is an JsProxy (object model).

Comment: I included an image to explain better the behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround solution.

I used computed binding method, no more `on-change` event. This form, I passed the paper-input value reference on method call, and all time that value change, the method is called.

The code changed:

**.html**

```
...
<paper-input label="Produto Componente" value="{{item_comp.descricao}}"></paper-input>
<span>{{mudou(item_comp.descricao)}}</span>
...
```

**.dart**

```
...
@reflectable
void mudou(a) {
  window.alert('teste');
}
...
```